# NTP Protocol Message parsing queries

Tags: ntp

I use the Chrony service to synchronize the time.
I don't quite understand why the Originator Timestamp is wrong in my NTP protocol message, but my system time is correct!I'm trying to figure out what the hell this Originator Timestamp field means.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k25MC.png)

I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm using the Chrony service as shown in the picture of the packet I grabbed during time synchronization, and it has the wrong Originator Timestamp, I don't really understand this.